# Reading a text file with strings and integers and testing it based on value (Java)

Tags: java, string, file, text

Here is what I would like to do. I want to create a simple text file with one string and one integer and have my program read from it in this format:

```
name 3
name2 4
name5 5
```

Just a string separated by a space and then an integer.

This is for a ranking system, so basically it takes the username of the member and sets their rank to the int, such as:

```
if (username.toLowerCase() == (stringFromFile)) {
rank = (rankFromFile)
}
```

I just cannot find anything on how to read multiple strings and ints from a file but test each one separately.

Here is the way I am doing it right now but I don't like how it looks in the code, so I would like to store the usernames elsewhere.

```
    private void RankLoad() {
    switch(username.toLowerCase()){
        case "example":
            rank = 3;
        break;
        case "example1":
            rank = 0;
        break;
        case "example2":
            rank = 0;
        break;
        case "example3":
            rank = 0;
        break;
}
```

Comment: language you are using?

Comment: @mic4ael He has a tag for Java.

Comment: read usernames and ranks to a hashmap and check if exists, then update the rank according to file.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, ah sorry, I think I had overlooked the tags.

Comment: And `==` is wrong when comparing Objects (as Strings). Use `equals`.

Comment: Use `username.toLowerCase().equals(stringFromFile)`. Comparing with `==` will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Scanner` and read the file line by line.  Then split the line by spaces: `line.split(" ");` Then parse the `int` which will be `[1]` of the array. Now you have your data parsed out so you can use it however you want...

Answer (score 0):

use something like this `Scanner scanner = new Scanner (new File("your_file.txt"));
scanner.useDelimiter(" ");` and then `while(scanner.hasNext()) {scanner.next() // use it to retrieve next value}`

Answer (score 0):

OP here, this is how I ended up doing it and I tested it and it works, if anyone has any suggestions I appreciate constructive criticism. Thanks

```
    public void readStaff() throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("stafflist.txt"));
    String player;
    int rank;
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        player = input.next();
        rank = input.nextInt();
    if (player.equals(username.toLowerCase())){
            rights = rank;
            } else {
                rights = 0;}}}

private void StaffLoad() {
    try { readStaff(); } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot Find stafflist.txt"); }}
```